# How to fix error invalid arguments Int32.TryParse in C# VS 2010?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use Int32.TryParse on code below to read integer input from user but I always get warning on Visual Studio that the method has some invalid arguments. How to fix this?
[See it on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQKep.png)

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                if(Int32.TryParse(token, out int result))
                {
                    dictionary.Add(i, new Point(result, result));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That syntax is not supported in that version (2010). I think, it is C# 7.0 feature. Either, you upgrade the compiler or write code the old way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out variables (`out int result`) are a C#7 feature that isn't supported in the VS2010 compiler. You should be able to avoid the error by declaring your variable separately on the line above:

```cs
int result;
if(Int32.TryParse(token, out result))
```